# How can i inspect .dmp files from windows with QtCreator

Tags: qt, debugging, dump

We are developing out Project with QtCreator 3.1.1 and Qt 5.2.1

Now we got .dmp files from `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\CrashDumps`

How can we load them into QtCreator to inspect where the App crashed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to leave this as a comment, but I don't believe Qt can open the .dmp files, they are more of a Microsoft thing. Visual Studio should work if you want to look at it, they have a free community version you can use.

However, that dmp file might not be overly useful, it will likely tell you what you already know (memory access error, etc). These are "small memory dump files" ( you can read more about accessing and configuring them here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315263 ). They have interesting information, but not necessarily the stack trace you're looking for. For example, the stack trace may just be the QtGui and QtCore dll's.

If the crash is reproducible you might have better luck causing the crash on a machine with Qt Creator installed so you can send it directly to debug as it crashes, assuming it's not reproducible when running locally in Qt.

Comment: Interesting. There is this ticket https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8834 and it says it was resolved in 2015, but my QtCreator built in 2020 still cannot open the dmp files, saying the ".dmp" file format is not recognized.